# Property 'previous' is missing in type - TypeScript + ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, setstate

Quite new to reactjs and ts.
I know why I am having this error, but I am not sure what would be the best fix for this

Currently using `reactjs` created an

## interface

```
interface IPropertyTax {
  annul: {
    current: number;
    previous: number;
  };
  monthly: {
    current: number;
    previous: number;
    difference: number
  };
}
```

## useState

```
    const [propertyTax, setPropertyTax] = useState<IPropertyTax>({
        annul: {
            current: 0,
            previous: 0
        },
        monthly: {
            current: 0,
            previous: 0,
            difference: 0
        }
    });
```

this action will be done trying to set the state

```
        setPropertyTax({
            ...propertyTax,
            annul: { current: validatedValue },
            monthly: { current: monthlyPropertyTax }
        });
```

Then I would get an error of `Property 'previous' is missing in type '{ current: number; }' but required in type '{ current: number; previous: number; }'`

I know it's because I didn't add `previous` since in my interface it's a required field.

So I thought maybe I should make them options such as

```
interface IPropertyTax {
  annul: {
    current?: number;
    previous?: number;
  };
  monthly: {
    current?: number;
    previous?: number;
    difference?: number
  };
}
```

but this would lead to `propertyTax.monthly.current` might be `Object is possibly 'undefined'` which I could just do `(propertyTax.monthly.current || 0)`

The above would work, but I didn't know if that's the a good option?

I thought of another way might be

```
        setPropertyTax({
            ...propertyTax,
            annul: { current: validatedValue, previous: propertyTax.annul.previous },
            monthly: { current: monthlyPropertyTax, previous: propertyTax.monthly.previous, difference: propertyTax.monthly.difference }
        });
```

But again, any of these are good options? or there is a better way to work this out?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you don't know for sure whether or not the property will exist, then yes you will need to check it. That is part of the point of TypeScript lol

Answer (score 0):

As u are not setting few properties, u are getting this error.

if u are trying to update the annual.current property then u can do like this

```
const newPropertyTax = propertyTax;
newPropertyTax?.annual?.current = validatedValue;
setPropertyTax(newPropertyTax);
```